# Where can I read Chuugakusei Nikki?

Tags: resources, meet-me-after-school

I have searched for *Chuugakusei Nikki* on popular websites, but couldn't find it. Are there any sites hosting it with an English translation?

Comment: Take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Answer (score 1):

No. according to [MangaUpdates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=98591) it as not been officially licensed in English nor is there any unofficial translations so the series is only available in Japanese

[image: Official license][image: Unofficial Translation]

Comment: Can you share link to japanese version of the manga?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan i've no idea of where you could legally read the raw version online if such a thing exists. i suspect [what the publisher has](https://www.futabasha.co.jp/booksdb/book/bookfind/index.html?type=t&word=%E4%B8%AD%E5%AD%A6%E6%80%A7%E6%97%A5%E8%A8%98&btnG=%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2) is only a preview and not the entire thing. however they do list where you can buy it and when i check the Amazon link for [volume 1](https://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/search?ie=UTF8&keywords=978-4-575-84341-5&tag=futabashanet-22&index=blended&linkCode=ur2&camp=247&creative=1211) i see kindle links

Comment: (cont.) so it might be possible to get the ebook version and read it on your PC. i'm not sure about the other sites they list